# How Generate an az container instance

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

a bit of context, I'm starting with the devOps, and create a docker-compose.yml to lift two containers, one with my mongodb and one with the express framework mongo-express, but now I want to bring it to my cloud in Azure, but the The truth is that the documentation is very limited and they do not give you a real example of how, for example, to upload a mongo db and that its data is persistent.

So, has anyone done something similar? Or do you have any advice that you can give me?

I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) to use a docker-compose file to deploy the containers to Azure Container Instance and this document also shows the example. And if you want to persist the database data, you can [mount the Azure File Share to the containers](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers).

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation in blue is poor and for people like me, who are starting in the world of devops perhaps it is insufficient, it seems that it is necessary to have a master in the azure cloud

Comment: @CarlosPetitQuintero What do you mean by a master? Is there any question you can't solve?

Comment: @CarlosPetitQuintero Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @CarlosPetitQuintero Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?